# AsyncStorage await issue with redux and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to send an axios request passing a token, this token is saved on my AsyncStorage. The problem is, when i make the call looks like its been sended without the AsyncStorage return the token, also the then/catch do not trigger.

Code example:

```
export const verificarPreco = (produto, estabelecimento) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `${API}preco/verificarPreco/?produto=${produto}&estabelecimento=${estabelecimento}`,
        headers: {
            "x-access-token": await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Offer4All:token")
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        verificarPrecoSucesso(response.data, dispatch);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        verificarPrecoErro(error.response, dispatch);
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: Do the await before you run the `axios()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use just `async/await` instead of handling the promises manually, and putting a `try/catch` around that.

```
export const verificarPreco = (produto, estabelecimento) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Offer4All:token");
      const request = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `${API}preco/verificarPreco/?produto=${produto}&estabelecimento=${estabelecimento}`,
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": token
        }
      });
      const response = await request.json();
      verificarPrecoSucesso(response.data, dispatch);
    } catch (error) {
      verificarPrecoErro(error.response, dispatch);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Sorry bother you again but it didn't work :( looks like the dispatcher is been skipped. The success and error functions don't trigger https://i.imgur.com/2kAkURn.png

Comment: @AlessandroMacanha That's frustrating. Is the axios request run at all?

Comment: No request is sent to api :(

Comment: @AlessandroMacanha Alright. To me it sounds like your issue is elsewhere. Maybe the function is not called at all?

Comment: The function is called but like I said looks like it's skipped https://m.imgur.com/2kAkURn?r

Comment: @AlessandroMacanha Yes, your `validarLocalizacao` function is called like you say, but the function returned from it might not be called.

Comment: Ok I removed the `const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Offer4All:token")` and the header of axios. Now the request is sent